# Rails, link different models in the same web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my database I have 3 models: drivers,reservations and section.
A driver can log-in and do a reservation where he select a date and a section.
How can I do a web page with these informations? In my actual web page the driver can only create a new date but can't select any section.

This is the _form.html file of reservation:

```
<%= form_for(@reservation) do |f| %>
  <% if @reservation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@reservation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this reservation from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @reservation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date, :start_year => Date.current.year, :start_month => Date.current.month, :start_day => Date.current.day %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have to add something here?

And here the models:

driver.rb

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    has_many :reservations
    has_secure_password
    attr_accessible :name, :surname, :address, :birth_date, :id,
                    :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 5 } , length: { maximum: 20 }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
    validates :surname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :birth_date, presence: true                
end
```

reservation.rb

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :driver
    belongs_to :driver
    belongs_to :section
    has_one :section
    belongs_to :leaving
    has_one :leaving
    attr_accessible :id, :date
end
```

section.rb

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.inheritance_column = nil
    has_many :reservations
    has_many :stops
    has_one :leaving
    attr_accessible :id, :loc_dep, :loc_arr, :type, :time
    validates :type, inclusion: { in: %w(weekday holiday daily scholastic)} , :allow_nil => false
    validates :loc_dep, presence: true
    validates :loc_arr, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
end
```

reservation_controller.rb

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_reservation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reservations
  # GET /reservations.json
  def index
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  # GET /reservations/1
  # GET /reservations/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reservations/new
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  # GET /reservations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reservations
  # POST /reservations.json
  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservation was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reservations/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reservations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.update(reservation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reservation, notice: 'Reservation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reservations/1
  # DELETE /reservations/1.json
  def destroy
    @reservation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reservations_url, notice: 'Reservation was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reservation
      @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    private
    def reservation_params
      params.require(:reservation).permit(:date).merge(driver_id: current_driver:id)
    end
```

Comment: `class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :driver
    belongs_to :driver`
Why has_one and belongs_to both?

Comment: I thinked that the model needs both

Answer (score 1):

You should share your controller code too. 
With assumptions you are having current_user object to identify which user(driver) is login and having driver_id column in reservations table.

This code may help you.

**Reservation Controller**

```
def create
 @reservation  = Reservations.new(reservation_params)
 if @reservation.save
  redirect_to reservations_path
 else
   render 'new'
 end 
end

private
def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:date).merge(driver_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: @Furla94.that syntax is correct.can you paste your reservation controller.so that i can look for the bug.

Comment: I paste it in the main message because it is too long

Comment: just paste create action and reservation_params

Comment: Ok now works without errors but I have the same page , there are no changes